# Streetview not displaying the image properly if the height of the map is greater

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have used the streetview according to the following

```
/* Map html */
<div id="mapDiv" class="">
    <div id="map-holder">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="bigmap"></div>
    <div id="map_stv" class="minimap" style="display: none"></div>
    </div>
</div>

/* Css associated */
.bigmap{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.minimap{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}
#map_stv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#map_stv img {
    border: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

When ever i need to show the streetview then i add the minimap class to the map_canvas and toggle map_stv. Its working fine. But when the dimensions of the map is 768x1024 then i get the following issue

[image]

Has anyone faced this? Any pointers on this?

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Ok i will try to put...

Comment: @chriz Just created the fiddle and saw that the issue is on Firefox only...Here is the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/fyDkD/6/show/ Plz suggest

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @chriz In the fiddle which i mentioned above, If you drag and drop the pegman then streetview will appear. This streetview is not proper in firefox and is working fine on chrome. How to get this fixed on firefox

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fyDkD/7/

Comment: @chriz it is still not proper in firefox.

Comment: It works for me in firefox

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26929/discussion-between-coder-slay-and-chriz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I made a fiddle for you!](http://jsfiddle.net/fyDkD/11/)

The problem is, is that your map was stretching too far for the images thus having the top of the streetview images cut off.

To make your map responsive I just added:

```
style="width: 99%; height: 99%;
```

To your `#map-holder` div.

In conclusion my best bet would be to try and stick to a more or less even aspect ratio with your map `width` and `height`